# Google Drive API using Service Account in python not showing up folders that are shared to me

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

The output only shows the google docs I own which I have shared with others, but not the ones I am shared to.
How can I see the folder structure and files shared to me ?

I am using my corporate Gmail account. Google service account is used.

Codes below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json' % path, scope)

# https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: If the email of the service account is not shared with the folder, when you share the email of the service account with the folder, what result will you get?

Comment: Got it fixed. Folder was not shared with service account

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be also useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike, it means that the email (from the service account) should be added as Viewer (or Editor -- as required) on the Google Drive folder

Answer (score 0):

The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
time.

[Link to documentation for google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)

```
def upload(name,id):
    creds = None
    

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'credentials.json')
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                file, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    folder_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    file_metadata = {'name': name,
    'parents':[id]
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload(name,mimetype='file/csv')
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).